# Excel VSTO AddIn - Get Chart Object from Selection

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio, charts, vsto

How would I cast a user's selection to a chart object (something like `Excel.Chart`) in a VSTO Add-In for Excel.

I've been trying to use something like this (while having a chart object selected in Excel):

`Dim chart as Excel.Chart = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection, Excel.Chart)`

However, this throws an `InvalidCastException`.

I just cannot seem to find any documentation on how to allow a user to select a chart and then modify the selected chart in a VSTO add-in.

Comment: try this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-Generate-tables-and-f19859b3

Comment: Thanks @dinotom but that example only shows how to add a chart (which seems to be the only documentation related to VSTO charting out there). In my case, I want to alter an existing chart that the user has selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to determine whether the Selection actually contains a Chart object and then derive the Chart from that. In order to determine what a Selection contains, when using VB.NET use the TypeName method, which returns a String, then evaluate the string:

```
Public Function IsSelectionChart() as Boolean
    Dim cht As Excel.Chart
    Dim sSelectionType As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    sSelectionType = TypeName(xlApp.Selection)
    Select Case sSelectionType
        Case "ChartArea", "PlotArea", "Legend"
            cht = xlApp.Selection.Parent
            Debug.Print(cht.Name)
        Case "Series"
            cht = xlApp.Selection.Parent.Parent
            Debug.Print(cht.Name)
        Case "Axis" 'Parent is Worksheet
            Debug.Print("Can't determine the chart from an Axis")
        Case Else
            Debug.Print("Not a chart-related object")
    End Select

    If Not cht Is Nothing Then 
       Return True
    Else
       Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. One other issue that I was running into was that the behavior of "Selection" is a little weird when using breakpoints in the code. I was trying to set breakpoints to test and it was causing all sorts of weird issues. Once I removed the breakpoints and just let the code run it worked well. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnH "Walking" the code from Visual Studio (as opposed to VBA) to see what's happening doesn't work, unfortunately - I've often wished it would! If I have a problem where I want/need to see each step I'll do it in VBA until I get all the wrinkles ironed out, then transfer the code back to VB.NET or C#. Just the difference between running in- and out-of process...